# C recursive function to find minimum

Tags: c, algorithm

I'm writing a program:

For example input is 5 ( it can be not only 5 ) numbers and I read data in array: `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`. I can choose some element from this array ( not first or last ), e.g. 3, then I delete this number in array, and to `sum` (which initially is 0 ) adding multiplied first-to-the-left with first-to-the-right elements ( means `2*4` in this case ). Resulted array is `1, 2, 4, 5`, then I do it again and again until number of elements equals 2 ( exactly `1 and 5` as we can't delete those numbers ).

For example: (where A, B, C, D are pairs of numbers 1 and 2, 2 and 3 and etc.. )

```
 A B C D
1 2 3 4 5
```

There are 6 possible combinations of the order deleting elements ( and adding left-right multiplication to sum ):

```
A (B (C D))
A ((B C) D)
(A B) (C D)
(A (B C)) D
((A B) C) D
A (B (C D))
```

The goal is to find smallest sum! There are 2 ways of solving, some clever algorithm or using recursion for every combination and then choosing smallest one. Can anyone give me a tip how to write such recursion, where to start writing ( or perhaps some clever algorithm ). Tnx

Comment: I don't understand why there are five combinations. You can delete all but the end elements, and the deletions can be done in any order. For a list with 5 elements, that would make (5-2)! = 6 combinations. (They are: (2, 3, 4), (2, 4, 3), (3, 2, 4), (3, 4, 2), (4, 2, 3), (4, 3, 2).) In your example you would never pair 1 and 2 because there is nothing between them to remove!

Comment: could you please put operation in your examples `A (B (C D))`

Comment: sort the list in increasing order and keep deleting the element at position 2nd-from the left-- 2, 3, 4 in that order in your eg. the sum doesnt get any lower than this.

Comment: @ashley: I believe the order of his list is predetermined.

Comment: @jma good to go then. just keep removing at the left.

Comment: Your approach doesn't work if the list is (5, 4, 3, 2, 1).

Comment: Could be just me - but I read the question 3 times already and failed to understand what exactly are you after. Won't a minimal subset be sum be the empty one? Can you formally define what exactly you are after? :|

Comment: @amit - I believe OP wants to delete all interior elements in an order that minimizes the resulting sum. (There may be more than one such order, of course.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The recursive backtracking solution is fairly straightforward (pseudocode):

```
def solve (list): 
    if list.length == 2:
        return 0
    ans = INFINITY
    for each interior element:
        remove element from list
        ans = min(ans, leftelement * rightelement + solve(list))
        place element back in original position in list
    return ans
```

However, this algorithm is not fast enough to work on non-trivial datasets, as its runtime is factorial `(O(n!))`. The usual method to optimize recursive solutions is [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming). Let's come up with the substates:

```
dp[a][b]: minimum cost to reduce array[a .. b] to two elements on the edge
          (array[a] and array[b])
```

The base cases are `dp[i][i + 1], i = {0 .. size - 1)` (two adjacent elements). Since there are no interior elements to delete, this substate is set to 0.

For all other cases `dp[a][b]` where `b - a >= 2`, we can divide `array[a .. b]` by removing any interior element indexed between `[a + 1, b - 1]`. If we divide the subarray on element i, the cost is `dp[a][i] + dp[i][b] + array[a] * array[b]`. We want to minimize the cost for each substate, so we will take the minimum of these values for all possible dividing elements. The final answer is simply `dp[0][size - 1]`.

Since there are `O(n^2)` substates, each with an average of `O(n)` dividing elements to consider, the total runtime is cubic `(O(n ^ 3))`, which should run for small to medium datasets in a reasonable time.

Comment: The run time on this algorithm is lower bounded to O(n!). I think you misread the question.

Comment: Yes, the first algorithm is O(n!) due to the recursive nature. However, the second algorithm reduces it to cubic time. The runtime analysis at the bottom is for the improved dynamic programming solution.

Comment: It worked for me, especially dynamic programming method, tnx a lot!